# I'm trying to make google map stay on right side of page when scrolling down

Tags: html, maps, flexbox

I am using flex to display three columns. One column is going to have a list of filters the middle column is going to have an index of items and the right column is going to have the map.  When I scroll down I want the map to stay visible.  I am using flex to make the columns.  I've tried many different ways but still can't get it to work.

```
<div class="indexpage">
    <div>
        some code
    </div>

    <div>
        some code
    </div>
    <div >
        <div class="map-position">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want that third div to stay fixed when I scroll down.  I also have a header in the layout that needs to not be covered initially.

Comment: Can you add your CSS to your question so we can see what you've tried already?

Comment: This isn't a Ruby question.

Answer (score 0):

to fix your div you must add a "`position: fixed;`" in your css. here is an example :

```
.map-position{
position: fixed; no-repeat;
left: 50%;
margin-left:60%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 50%;
width: auto;
height: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: so this sticks it to the top of the screen but not in the div and I have a header too so it covers that.